# How to send email through Gmail using OAuth in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-api

I have successfully sent emails in my application using OAuth 1.0a (using Signpost) by constructing an XOAUTH string as described [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#smtp_protocol_exchange). The problem is that access tokens expire after an hour and this XOAUTH won't authenticate the user for SMTP server after that.

Is there a way to extend/refresh the access token's lifetime without user's intervention? I know [this Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilvec.smsforwarder) does that, but how?

I managed to upgrade to OAuth 2.0 (using Scribe) where I'm given a refresh token as well, but it looks like Gmail XOAUTH doesn't support OAuth 2.0 tokens. Does Google provide another way to send emails?

Comment: UPDATE: GMail now supports XOAUTH with IMAP and SMTP on OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to fix it.
The OAuth 1.0 access token is actually long-lived, but the XOAUTH string is valid for a short period of time, hence needs to be created/signed frequently.

Comment: This is my code: http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/android-app-to-send-g-mails-through.html